# Set width of div equally with CSS

Tags: css

How can I set those divs to be equally, I gave it first `width:50%;` bu then I wanted to set a margin for each one, so I set the width to 49% and gave it `margin-right:1%;` but it doesn't seem right because I have also margin-right on the right

Code:

```
ul li { 
    list-style-type:none;
    background:#f29;
    width:49%;
    height:100px;
    float:left;  
    margin-right:1%; 
    margin-bottom:1%;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/bnjv39o3/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `box-sizing: border-box` which makes the `width: 50%` take into account the `padding` & `border` and then you can remove the `margin-right`

Comment: I don't see the solution, I have tried and it's the same

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bnjv39o3/4/ this is working. If you want the white space between the boxes then you'd surround the content in the `<li>` with another element like so: http://jsfiddle.net/bnjv39o3/5/

Comment: and what is different between your example to my example?

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` and the `margin-right` was removed

Comment: It was removed, but there is still space on the right, so the result is the same, basically it doesn't answer the question, my code does the same thing with less properties

Comment: In that case you have to use the `:nth-child` pseudo to target the elements that you want to apply the margin to: http://jsfiddle.net/bnjv39o3/6/

Answer (score 1):

Using Flexbox this can be easily accomplished. See [this](http://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard)

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 150%;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.paddingBlock {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.eqWrap {
  display: flex;
}

.eq {
  padding: 10px;
}

.eq:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: yellow;
}

.eq:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: lightblue;
}


.equalHMRWrap {
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.equalHMR {
  width: 49%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="paddingBlock">

  <div class="equalHMRWrap eqWrap">
    <div class="equalHMR eq">boo</div>
    <div class="equalHMR eq">shoo</div>
    <div class="equalHMR eq">clue</div>
    <div class="equalHMR eq">boo <br> boo </div>
    <div class="equalHMR eq">shoo</div>
    <div class="equalHMR eq">clue</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox isn't hard...look at the code, it's 3 lines of css that make it happen.

Comment: Can't I do that without Flex? it doesn't support all browsers

Comment: IE8, IE9, No it's not

Comment: Aren't those long gone?

Comment: Unfortunately, IE9 is quiet popular but I prefer flexbox myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this but adding `padding-left` & `padding-top` to the parent

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #f29;
  width: 49%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>BOX1</li>
  <li>BOX2</li>
  <li>BOX3</li>
  <li>BOX4</li>
  <li>BOX5</li>
  <li>BOX6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use child selectors. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bnjv39o3/3/)

```
ul li { 
list-style-type:none;
background:#f29;
width:49.5%;
height:100px;
float:left;  
margin-bottom:1%;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd)
{ margin-right:0.5%; 
}

ul li:nth-child(even)
{margin-left:0.5%;}
```